# Cannot ping RHEL hosts using ansible. Error: 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, virtualbox, redhat

I'm new to Ansible. I am trying to ping 2 RHEL targets from my host using ansible. I have an inventory file set up like the following:

```
target1 ansible_host=192.168.43.142 ansible_user=target_user ansible_ssh_password=target_pass
target2 ansible_host=192.168.43.8 ansible_user=target_user ansible_ssh_password=target_pass
```

Ansible command I'm using:

> ansible all -vvv -m ping -i inventory.txt

Below is the message I receive. Please not that regular ssh to both target machines are working fine

```
ansible 2.9.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/target_user/ansible/test-project/inventory.txt as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/target_user/ansible/test-project/inventory.txt as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/target_user/ansible/test-project/inventory.txt as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /home/target_user/ansible/test-project/inventory.txt as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/target_user/ansible/test-project/inventory.txt inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
<192.168.43.142> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: target_user
<192.168.43.142> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="target_user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/79ae0eeb97 192.168.43.142 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~target_user && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.43.8> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: target_user
<192.168.43.8> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="target_user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/d23adc63a3 192.168.43.8 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~target_user && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.43.142> (255, '', 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
target1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
<192.168.43.8> (255, '', 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
target2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You perhaps better ask this at https://superuser.com.

Comment: You are using key based ssh or password based ?

Answer (score 0):

That error message is just an SSH error message.  Since you're specifying the `ansible_user` and `ansible_ssh_password`, you might want to confirm that the user specified (`target_user`) can login using `target_pass`.

It's also possible that the target machines don't let `target_user` login with a password.

It's hard to be more specific from this error message.  Try running your Ansible command with "-vvv" and update the question with this additional text.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem. You can try adding -k option in the end.

```
ansible all -vvv -m ping -i inventory.txt -k
```